# Thread-safety of javax.servlet.Servlet#getServletConfig()

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, thread-safety

I am wondering why calling `javax.servlet.Servlet#getServletConfig()` is thread safe: if you check the implementation in 
`javax.servlet.GenericServlet` from servlet API 3.0.1, you see the following:

```
package javax.servlet;

// lines omitted

public abstract class GenericServlet 
    implements Servlet, ServletConfig, java.io.Serializable
{
    // lines omitted

    private transient ServletConfig config;

    // lines omitted

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config = config;
    this.init();
    }

    // lines omitted

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
    return config;
    }
    // lines omitted
}
```

The field `config` is written in `init(ServletConfig)` without any synchronization, locking or `config` being volatile, while `getServletConfig()` could be called anytime from any later worker thread of the servlet container. I took a quick look into Tomcat/Catalina code base, however I see no indication of the servlet container performing any magic, which would guarantee thread safe access to field `config` through `getServletConfig()` from e.g. `javax.servlet.GenericServlet#service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)` and the corresponding methods in `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

Am I missing something here? What will guarantee that if Thread A is used to `init(ServletConfig)` then Thread B calling `getServletConfig()` will see the correct state of the field `config` (Java *"happens-before"*), and not e.g. `null`?

Answer (score 1):

`ServletConfig` is a singleton object (managed by container) and you use it only to retrieve the `init-parameters` or to get `servletcontext` or servletname set during the servlet `init` phase. 
You can't write anything to `ServletConfig` object, rather container alone manages this object, so, it is thread safe.

**The field config is written in init(ServletConfig) without any synchronization, locking or config being volatile, while getServletConfig() could be called anytime from any later worker thread of the servlet container ?**

`GenericServlet` is an abstract class for which the container will not create any object, rather the container creates an object (only a single instance by default) for the custom `HttpServlet` class that you write/provide by which it initializes the `ServletConfig` object.

**The question is about the thread-safety of `getServletConfig`() not of `ServletConfig` ?**

Once the container creates `ServletConfig` object during the servlet lifecycle's `init` phase, it never be changed. So, `getServletConfig`() is thread safe (i.e., it does not matter how many threads reading the `ServletConfig` object as long as none of threads are allowed to write anything to it).

> UPDATED QUESTION:
>
> What will guarantee that if Thread A is used to init(ServletConfig)
>   then Thread B calling getServletConfig() will see the correct state of
>   the field config (Java "happens-before"), and not e.g. null?

The servlet container calls the init method exactly once after instantiating the servlet. **The init method must complete successfully before the servlet can receive any requests.**
The servlet container cannot place the servlet into service if the init method Throws a ServletException or Does not return within a time period defined by the Web server. You can look at [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Servlet.html)

**The creation of the user request threads happens ONLY AFTER the completion of the init() method successfully.** So, there is no need for data (`servletconfig`) synchronization between the user request threads because **the `servletconfig` object is already made available even before the user request threads have been created**.

Comment: The question is about the thread-safety of `getServletConfig()` not of `ServletConfig`.

Comment: Yes, it's about the visibility of the field: extended question to be clearer here.

Comment: Added the explanation, let me know you need more clarity on this

Comment: @javaguy In theory `getServletConfig()` could keep returning `null` from other threads, after being initialized in one thread since there are no steps taken to ensure visibility to other threads (such as having a volatile field or synchronized methods). It doesn't matter that it's not changed after creation.

Comment: @javaguy The answer still doesn't address the issue that assignment from a different thread is not necessarily visible to other threads unless steps are taken to ensure it.

Comment: The point here is that the user request thread(s) itself will not be created until init is completed.

Comment: @javaguy Where do you see that stated? If you start a servlet engine and deploy 3 servlets with 1 minute in between, are you saying that the servlet engine's threadpool is recreated after each deploy?

Comment: I did not completely understand your question, but Thread pool is about how many concurrent request threads allowed per each servlet,
the pool will be added with each servlet & concurrent threads allowed, which happens for all servlets specified during the container start up, however, this logic is purely internal to the container vendor upto how they manage. But the init() of the servlet object should already be done before adding the servlet threads to the pool.

Comment: @javaguy You claimed that all user request threads would be created only after servletconfig is set, but any realistic servlet engine would use a threadpool for user requests. This would make your claim that "user request thread itself will not be created until init is completed" false, or it would require that the servlet engine recreate its threadpool after initializing a servlet (which is unlikely).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127633/discussion-between-javaguy-and-kayaman).

Comment: @javaguy: It makes sense, what you write, but only if we assume that all servlets are loaded at startup. However, the Servlet JSR does not guarantee this:
([JSR-315 / Servlet 3.0](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr315/index.html])) section 2.3.1 _Loading and Instantiation: ... The loading and instantiation can occur when the container is started, or **delayed until the container determines the servlet is needed to service a request.**_